# Does the country where you do a postdoc matter (irrespectively of other aspects)?

Tags: postdocs, early-career

I am looking for postdocs, and I have different postdoc offers.
I am really hesitating between different possibilities.

Some of those offers are interesting, in a dynamic group and they are in eastern Europe countries.

I was wondering if compared to a post-doc in a country such as the U.S for instance it can be badly seen on a curriculum (for an academic carreer).

I plan to do a career in Western Europe (ideally in France). Also, some answer suggested to do a postdoc in the same place where you want to find a position. Actually I did my PhD in France and for this reason I have to go outside of the country for networking purpose.

Comment: Does the move excite you?

Answer (score 3):

What matters is more what you do, less where you do it.  Of course ideally it’s best to do great work in a group with high visibility, but the visibility of the group is often country-independent.  In addition, it’s likely that, if you want to remain in the same field, these high-visibility groups will be well known to prospective employers.

The tricky part is to assess if your work will get proper recognition, and this implies - in addition to the core value fo the work - opportunities to promote your work through conferences or workshops, the abiiity to interact with others through a vigorous visitor program, and such things that basically boil down to $$.

Certainly in physics there are extremely good and well recognized groups in Eastern Europe.

Answer (score 1):

There are some truly fine universities in Eastern Europe. There might be some advantage, however, in doing the post doc in the same place that you want to build a career since it is easier for others to make judgments.

The exception would be for a really interesting opportunity that isn't likely to have a counterpart elsewhere. And one that won't raise questions about relevance for your career.

Comment: It's also likely that one's academic network will be strongest or largest in the country or region where one is working. So in addition for easier judgment by others in the same county, generally, it can turn out of to be of great benefit to be doing a postdoc in the same country (or in a country with strong connections or lots of professional exchange) where one would like to establish one's career.